# Remove Tags from string, Stored from ckeditor

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor

I'm trying to echo value in PHP, which is stored in database using ckeditor, the value stored in database is something like

```
&lt;p&gt;sample text&lt;/p&gt;
```

now im printing value using

```
<?php echo $row[0]->content; ?>
```

but the output I'm getting is

```
<p>sample text</p>
```

how to remove **p** tags from string?

Comment: [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), then `strip_tags`

Comment: perfect solution, Thank you

Comment: Do we lose styling with it too? like list, heading, bold etc? @u_mulder

Comment: See my answer, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String `&lt;p&gt;sample text&lt;/p&gt;` includes some encoded html entities (`&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`).

If you want to replace this encoded entitites with real symbols - use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php). After it, your string becomes `<p>sample text</p>`. So if you echo it, `<p>` and `</p>` will be considered html-tags and will not be shown.

If you still need to remove these tags - use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

In the end:

```
<?php echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($row[0]->content)); ?>
```

And **yes**, `strip_tags` removes **all** tags from a string unless you use it's second parameter.